# I am getting this "fatal: bad object refs/remotes/origin/index_ui_changes" due to which i am getting this error

Tags: amazon-web-services, git, github, gitlab, github-actions

fatal: bad object refs/remotes/origin/ index-ui-changes
error: https://git-codecommit.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/**/**/** did not send all necessary objects

I am getting this error I have even deleted the branch from local as well as from remote but still I am not able to pull the origin main.

It all started because when I published the branch in next 3 to 4 sec battery power got off due to some battery problem but till then branch was visible in code-commit so I raised the pull request and that when I made changes in local I was not getting option of sync change so I tried to commit

Initially I tried
git f s c k
--> git branch -D index-ui-changes
--> git fetch
and then this
git reflog

but not solved then
I deleted the remote branch and pulled the origin main

Comment: Sounds to me like you have a corrupted sandbox. If you don't have local changes in that sandbox, I would discard it and start from a fresh clone. If you do have local changes, I might still discard it and start fresh, copying the updated files from the corrupted sandbox to the new one.